# OpenVPN bad source address from client

Tags: openvpn, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenVPN bad source address from client](https://serverfault.com/questions/440909/openvpn-bad-source-address-from-client)

I have one problem with OpenVPN.
There are a lot drops records in the openvpn log file on the server:

*Mon Oct 22 10:14:41 2012 us=726541 laptop/ххх:1194 MULTI: bad source address from client [192.168.1.107], packet dropped*

```
grep -E "^[a-z]" server.conf  
-----
port 1194  
proto udp
dev tun 
ca data/ca.crt 
cert data/server.crt
key data/server.key 
dh data/dh1024.pem 
tls-server
tls-auth data/ta.key 0
remote-cert-tls client 
cipher AES-256-CBC
tun-mtu 1200
server 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
max-clients 5
status /var/log/status-openvpn.log
log  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 4
auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/verify.sh via-file
tmp-dir /tmp
script-security 2
-----

cat ccd/laptop
-----
iroute 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
-----

cat client.conf 
-----
remote server ip 1194
client
dev tun
ping 10

comp-lzo
proto udp
tls-client
tls-auth data/ta.key 1
pkcs12 data/vpn.laptop.p12

remote-cert-tls server
#ns-cert-type server
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-CBC

verb 3
pull

auth-user-pass /home/user/.openvpn/users.db 
-----
```

According to "Jan Just Keijser - OpenVPN 2 Cookbook" root of the problem is incorrect config options.

See the screenshot
[image: See the screenshot]

**But, as you see, my config has such options.
Could you please help me to solve this problem.**